# Start timer from different class

Tags: c#, class, timer

In my form I have one button and one label, and in my class I have one timer and it should start with `timer.Start();`

- I need help because I need to start the timer in my form with one `button1_Click` but I can´t start the timer and where I should have the elapsed event in form or in class timer?

So when I click in the start button in my Form the timer should start, in my Timer.cs, and label in form should show timer time

Timer.CS

```
        public class Timer
        {
    public string TimerType { get; set; }
            public Timer PersonUnlimitedTimer { get; set; }

            public enum TypeTimer { Unlimited, Countdown, Limited}

            int timervalue;
            int minute = 60;
            int second = 0;

            //Valor a ser alterado pelo user
            int final = 1;

            public Timer()
            {
                timervalue = final * minute;

                PersonUnlimitedTimer = new Timer();
                PersonUnlimitedTimer.Interval = 1000;
                PersonUnlimitedTimer.Elapsed += _PersonUnlimitedTimer_Elapsed;
                PersonUnlimitedTimer.Start();

            }

            public Timer(TypeTimer s1)
            {
                switch (s1)
            {
                case TypeTimer.Unlimited:
                    second++;
                    TimeSpan unlimited_timer = new TimeSpan(0, 0, second);
                    TimerTime = unlimited_timer.ToString();
                    break;

                case TypeTimer.Countdown:
                         if (second != timervalue)
                         {
                             timervalue--;
                             TimeSpan countdown_timer = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timervalue);
                             TimerTime = countdown_timer.ToString();
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             PersonUnlimitedTimer.Stop();
                         }

                         break;
                case TypeTimer.Limited:
                        if (second != timervalue)
                        {
                            second++;
                            TimeSpan limited_timer = new TimeSpan(0, 0, second);
                            TimerTime = limited_timer.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PersonUnlimitedTimer.Stop();
                        }

                        break;
                default:
                        break;
            }
            }
public void _PersonUnlimitedTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            second++;
            TimeSpan unlimited_timer = new TimeSpan(0, 0, second);

            TimerTime = unlimited_timer.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and this is my form

```
namespace Time
{
    public partial class Timers : Form
    {
        Timer timer;
        public Timers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Timers(Timertimer): this()
        {
            this.timer= timer;
            timer.PersonUnlimitedTimer.Elapsed += PersonUnlimitedTimer_Elapsed;

        }

        void PersonUnlimitedTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            lblTimerTime.Text = timer.TimerTime;
        }

        private void Timers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.PersonUnlimitedTimer.Start();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            timer.PersonUnlimitedTimer.Stop();
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.PersonUnlimitedTimer.Stop();
            lblTimerTime.Text = "00:00:00";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the 'Start()' and 'Stop()' definitions? I don't see them in the code example. Also, the properties for 'Interval' and 'Elapsed' are not defined.

Comment: The code you've shown here should not compile, because your `Timer` class has the same name as `System.Timers.Timer`, which it uses internally without specifying its full name. You're also missing a parameter name in the second `Timers` constructor. Either way, what did you try and what problems did you encounter?